# How to sort an array of objects based on a property and another array giving the desired order?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, sorting

I have the following array:

```
var my_list = ["XXXS", "XXS", "XS", "S", "M", "L", "XL", "XXL", "XXXL"];
```

Then I've the following array of objects that I get from json:

```
my_json = [
    {
        size: "L",
        color: "black"
    }, {
        size: "M",
        color: "blue"
    }, {
        size: "XXL",
        color: "red"
    }, {
        size: "XXS",
        color: "red"
    }
];
```

I'm trying to sort the array of objects by the `size` basing in the order of `my_list`
I've found sort functions, but it sorts alphabetically, I don't know if there is a simple way to do it.

Here is a jsfiddle where you can try: http://jsfiddle.net/ew3ZU/3/

To be clear:

**ACTUAL OUTPUT**

```
[{"size":"L","color":"black"},{"size":"M","color":"blue"},{"size":"XXL","color":"red"},{"size":"XXS","color":"red"}]
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
[{"size":"XXS","color":"red"},{"size":"M","color":"blue"}{"size":"L","color":"black"},{"size":"XXL","color":"red"}]
```

Comment: `Here is a jsfiddle where you can try:`  so sweet..! But what did you try..?

Comment: *"Then I've the following json:"* That's not JSON, that's also just an array (in this case, of objects). Hint: If you're in JavaScript code, it's not JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have give it a try :

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Brewal/ew3ZU/7/)

```
var ordered_list = [];

for (i = 0; i < my_list.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < my_json.length; j++) {
        if (my_list[i] == my_json[j].size) {
            ordered_list.push(my_json[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `for-in` to loop through arrays [unless you do it properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/how-to-do-for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476).

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this:

```
//only modern browsers support indexOf method for an array
my_list.indexOf = function(e){
  for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
    if(this[i] === e) return i;
  }
  return -1;
};
//the sorter to compare 2 object based on the property size.
function sorter(a,b){
  var s1 = my_list.indexOf(a.size);
  var s2 = my_list.indexOf(b.size)
  return s1 > s2 ? 1 : s1 < s2 ? -1 : 0;
}
my_json.sort(sorter);
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/ew3ZU/11/)

Comment: ***Please*** don't overwrite `Array.prototype.indexOf` if it's already provided by the JavaScript implementation!! (Which it is in all modern browsers.)

Comment: I think the custom sorter function should return the difference of the two indexes when they exist.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort  ;  there is also a question of what to do if the index is undefined, because the property has an unexpected value, and whether that might require some if blocks to test and use alphabetical at the end of the list or similar.

Comment: @Paul yes, missed that.

Answer (score 1):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ew3ZU/10/)**
     try this

```
 var newMyJson = [];
for (var i = 0; i < my_list.length; i++) {

    var value = my_list[i];
    $.each(my_json, function (i, val) {

        if (value == val.size) {
            newMyJson.push(my_json[i]);
            return;
        }

    });
}
```